# Logic puzzle - truthtellers and liars

Tags: logic

I have a question about an island of knights and knaves where knights always speak the truth and knaves always lie.

Now, if A says 'I am a knave and B is a knight' and B says nothing, then is A a knave and B a knave?

Comment: If $A$ is a knight then the statement isn't true,but knights never lie hence $A$ isn't a knight.Now if $A$ is a knave then she's lying hence the statement is false so $B$ is not a knight hence it's a knave.

Comment: This should be asked on Puzzling SE?

Comment: So, my answer is correct? :)

Comment: I was also wondering if it might ever be possible to eliminate all four possible combinations in problems of this sort.

Comment: @fredsjdhh If you successfully eliminate all four possible combinations (of A and B being a knight or a knave), then you've proven that the story you've been told is inconsistent, so that story cannot be true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ tells the truth. Then $A$ is a knave, in which case he is lying, contradiction. If he is lying, then $A$ cannot be a knight since  otherwise he would be telling the truth. Thus he tells the truth about himself but lies about $B$. Thus both of them are knaves.

Regarding your further question, if $B$ tells that he is a knave, then all cases are eliminated. This is basically the self-refuting paradox (this might be incorrect terminology): "This sentence is false."